# Getting the sum of the floor values of the a vector in python

Tags: python, r

I am coming from an R background and am now trying to learn Python. At the moment, I am looking at how to do some calculations in Python that I use to do in R. For instance, to get the sum

[image]

in R, I could do something like

```
x <- 1:2015
dat <- rep(NA, times = 2015)
for (i in x){
  dat[i] <- floor(sqrt(i) / 10)
}
dat
sum(dat)
```

or

```
dat <- sapply(x, function(i) floor(sqrt(i) / 10))
sum(dat)
```

which gives the correct answer 5064.

However, the following code in Python gives me 5060.0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sum(np.floor(np.sqrt(range(1,2015)) / 10))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: As suggested by Gregor, the R code can be better written as `sum(floor(sqrt(x) / 10))`.

Comment: http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/ here for further reading

Comment: Just a note, in R all that is vectorized so you don't need `for` or `sapply`. You can do `dat = sum(floor(sqrt(x) / 10))`, just like the Python solution.

Comment: Noted, @Gregor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, the [`range(a,b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) generator provides an iterable from `a` to `b-1`, as reported in the documentation. To make a sum like that, jou need a `range(1, 2016)`

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(np.floor(np.sqrt(range(1,2016)) / 10))
```

Its because of the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function. Then last value is not included. So it is to be `2016` not `2015`

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that range(1,2015) only includes integers from 1 to 2014 included. you should use range(1,2016)

But you don't need pandas and numpy to do this : list comprehension is a more pythonic way to handle basic operations if time optimization is not an issue:

```
import math
myrange=range(1,2016)
result=sum([int(math.sqrt(k)/10) for k in myrange])
```